# Subquery in ON clause Laravel ORM

Tags: sql, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5.1

How can I create this query in Laravel ORM?

```
SELECT b1.* FROM `buildings` b1 INNER JOIN `buildings` b2 ON b2.`id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `ingame_buildings`) WHERE b1.`level` > b2.`level`
```

I tried to do in `->join()`:

```
function(){
    return implode(',',IngameBuilding::get());
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: your raw query does not make sense to me. You are essentially trying to `SELECT * FROM buildings where id IN ( SELECT id FROM ingame_buildings)`, and within the data set, you wanna compare `level` column?

Comment: @yangqi - I have two collumns. First - `buildings` with all building templates available in game - and second - `ingame_buildings` where I put data, about builded buildings in current city. I want to find all available upgrades - I have this data in `buildings` table, because I have fields `id`, `building_id` and `level`, where `building_id` and `level` are unique. Only can I have in `ingame_buildings` is `building_id` which references to `buildings.id` field.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, from what I understand there is `building_id` in both `buildings` and `ingame_buildings` tables, but they represent different meanings?

Comment: For simple I have building: City Hall. This building have 3 levels. So I have next 3 fields in `buildings`: `(id, building_id, level): (12, 1, 1), (34, 1, 2), (56, 1, 3)` - and `id` field is primary key ofc. Where player build a building, for simple have City Hall level 1, in `ingame_buildings` have: `(id, building_id, owner_id): (1, 12, 1)` but when have level 3 in base I have `(1, 56, 1)` :)

Comment: Ok, I got you. `building_id` in two different tables are indeed confusing. The one in buildings identify a unique building, but the one in `ingame_buildings` is a foreign key to identify a unique row in `buildings`. See the answer below, I'll add eloquent query later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query to get all the records in buildings that have level greater than the existing building level in `ingame_buildings`

```
SELECT * FROM buildings
JOIN (
      SELECT a.building_id, b.level 
      FROM ingame_buildings as a
      JOIN buildings as b ON a.building_id=b.id
     ) 
AS ingame_level ON ingame_level.building_id=buildings.id
WHERE buildings.level > ingame_level.level
```

Comment: In condition `ingame_level.building_id=buildings.id` you should use `buildings.building_id` for correct working, but thank you so mutch bro! :)